# Java : Get only 1 line of integers from the console?

Tags: java, input, console, newline

I recently picked up Java and I am having an issue with some console input.

Basically, I want to read in an array of ints from the console in a format like this :

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

I looked through some examples on the forums and decided to do this by using the scanner ***nextInt()*** method.

My code currently looks like this :

```
Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);
List<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<>();

while (get.hasNextInt()) {           
        elements.add(get.nextInt());
    }
```

The problem with this code is that the while loop doesn't stop when I hit "Enter" on the console. 
Meaning that after I enter some numbers (1 3 5 7) and then hit enter, the program doesn't continue with execution, but instead waits for more integers. The only way it stops is if I enter a letter to the console.

I tried adding ***!get.hasNextLine()*** as a condition in my while loop, but this didn't help.

I would be very greatful, if anyone has an idea how can I fix this.

Comment: Give input within double quotes as `"1 2 3 4 5 6"`, read it with `nextLine()`, later split it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to read **only one line** the simpliest answer may be the best :)

`Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String hString = in.nextLine();
        String[] hArray = hString.split(" ");`

Now, in array hArray you have all elements from input and you can call them like hArray[0]

Comment: Thank you. Although it is not directly reading in an int, but rather reading a string and the splitting and parsing it. It is a very neat solution to my problem :) +1

Comment: yes, you're wright - but you can simple parse string to int by Integer.parseInt(yourString) method

Answer (score 1):

You can read one line, and then use that to construct another `Scanner`. Something like,

```
if (get.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = get.nextLine();
    Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
    while (lineScanner.hasNextInt()) {          
        elements.add(lineScanner.nextInt());
    }
}
```

The [`Scanner(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.lang.String-) constructor (per the Javadoc) *constructs a new `Scanner` that produces values scanned from the specified string.*

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);
String arrSt = get.next();
StringTokinizer  stTokens = new StringTokinizer(arrSt," ");
int [] myArr = new Int[stTokens.countTokens()];
int i =0;
while(stTokens.hasMoreTokens()){
    myArr[i++]=Integer.parseInt(stTokens.nextToken());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)

You may use the following. User just has to enter each integer without pressing enter and press enter at the end.

```
Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);
List<Integer> elements = Stream.of(get.nextLine().split(" "))
                               .map(Integer::parseInt)
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```